# How to get Django South to migrate a field with changed max_length?

Tags: python, django, django-south

I have a `CharField` in a model for which I want to increase the `max_length` attribute. South isn't noticing this change, saying there's nothing to migrate. How do I get it to migrate this?

Comment: What database backend are you using?

Comment: Did you run `schemamigration my_app --auto` first? That creates new migrations. `migrate` then applies them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Issue the command (after the change of the `max_length` in the code):

```
python manage.py schemamigration <name of the app> --auto
python manage.py migrate <name of the app>
```

That worked for me.
Hope it helps

Comment: Duh, forgot to do the schemamigration and stupidly assumed it had something to do with max_length. Thanks. Was going to delete this question but someone upvoted it so perhaps it will be useful to someone else.